# Stack around the variable 'dim'(not an array) was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fstream, corrupt

I'm trying to read from a binary file, using fstream, some data I have previously written there.

The problem is that after getting to the end of the function the message in the subject is shown

The code is the following:

```
ifstream in("contrib.bin", ios::in | ios::binary );

char *nume, dim;
in.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(int));
nume = new char[dim + 1];
in.read(nume, dim);
nume[dim] = '\0';
double imp;
in.read((char*)&imp, sizeof(double));

delete [] nume;
```

Now, I've done my homework and looked for this issue, but the other people who faced it had arrays, whereas my variable is a simple char.

Can someone point me to the right direction, please?

Comment: Instead of raw arrays and `new` and `delete`, use a `std::vector` or a `std::string`, depending on how you intend to use the data. To pass a pointer to the first byte in a vector or a string `v`, use `&v[0]`. Note however that as opposed to the current code this is UB for size 0, so you need to check for size 0 (if that can occur).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code

```
char dim;
in.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(int));
```

defines a 1 byte char then reads `sizeof(int)` bytes (which is likely to be greater that 1) into it.  This is invalid and may corrupt your stack.

If you need to read `sizeof(int)` bytes, declare `dim` as `int`.  Otherwise, change the number of bytes you read to 1.  It'd be best if you also used `sizeof(dim)` to ensure that you only read as many bytes as you've provided storage for:

```
in.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(dim));
```

Comment: It *could* corrupt the stack. For all we know it could also send the computer flying across the room. ;-)

Comment: "reads 4 bytes" is not necessarily true, since the sizeof(int) depends on the platform in more ways than one (size of a byte and amount of bits used for an int).

Comment: @netcoder I know this isn't strictly true in general but since the question mentioned a stack corruption error I thought it was a fair assumption here.  I've updated my answer along the lines you were suggesting though.

Comment: Much better. :) You get a tasty +1 to munch on.

Comment: "(which will be greater that 1)" is not necessarily true. ordinarily it is true, and in the OP's case it is overwhelmingly probably true. but not as a general statement.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf http://stackoverflow.com/a/589684/311966 implies that int will always be at least 2 bytes (assuming 8 bits per byte).  Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @simonc You can't assume eight-bit bytes. They may be larger. If `CHAR_BIT >= 16`, `sizeof(int)` could be 1.

Answer (score 7):

`in.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(int));` is not correct, `dim` only holds `sizeof(char)` which is one, but you're attempting to read `sizeof(int)` into it.

All gloves are off after this.

Comment: Unless `sizeof(int)` happens to be 4. Unusual, but not impossible.

Comment: @PeteBecker do you mean "happens to be 1"?

Answer (score 2):

Well you define a character then read in the size of an int. That would be the first issue

```
char *nume, dim;
in.read((char*)&dim, sizeof(char));
```